# Woocommerce working in 2 environments (development and production)

Tags: database, wordpress, merge, woocommerce, synchronization

I have 2 environments: one for development(dev) and another in production(prod) where already I have some costumers and orders.

All the products are are different with variations and where the client can do some customization.

So 'prod' has all the finished products, orders and clients. While 'dev' has the upcoming products, new functionalities, general options, etc.

So can you think a way where we can sync or merge the databases (not replace or override)?

Thanks
Pepe

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Wp MigrateDB Pro.

It's not free, but it truly does an amazing job at synchronizing WP databases.

https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/

Comment: Yes, I love that plugin and maybe you are right. Migrate only the selected tables and excluding post_types can be the "solution". While this solution will still be overriding some data.